# Android Show AlertDialog from Timer thread

Tags: android, multithreading, android-alertdialog

I have a background thread that is started from a Timer. The thread runs every 60 seconds and may detect a fatal problem that requires the app to exit immediately. Before exiting I want to show an alert dialog. Because the thread runs every 60 seconds I have no way of knowing which activity is currently running. Without an activity I can't call runOnUiThread to show the alert dialog. Below is some code that should illustrate what I'm trying to do. Without knowing the current activity how do I get an AlertDialog to show on the UI thread?

```
public class Foo {
    private Timer mTimer;
    public void startRefresh() {
        if (mTimer == null) {
            mTimer = new Timer(true);
            mTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    boolean succeeded = true;

                    // Do something that fails
                    succeeded = false;

                    if (!succeeded) {
                        // Display alert dialog on UI thread before exiting application
                    }                   
                }
            }, 60000, 60000);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass the activity context to the Foo constructor

```
public class Foo {
    Context mContext;

    // constructor
    public Foo(Context context){
        this.mContext = context;
    }
     ...    
    if (!succeeded) {
    // Display alert dialog on UI thread before exiting application
    } 
}


public void displayAlert(Context context){
  AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    alertDialog.setTitle("Display alert");
    alertDialog.setMessage("My Alerts");

    // Showing Alert Message
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

---

**EDIT**

> Which activity? The whole problem is that the Activity that started
>   the timer may not be the current activity when the error is detected.

Then don't use the constructor just use `getApplicationContext()` instead:

> public abstract Context getApplicationContext ()
>
> Added in API level 1 Return the context of the single, global
>   Application object of the current process. This generally should only
>   be used if you need a Context whose lifecycle is separate from the
>   current context, that is tied to the lifetime of the process rather
>   than the current component.

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                // Your dialog code.
                }
            });
```

Comment: Which activity? The whole problem is that the Activity that started the timer may not be the current activity when the error is detected.

Comment: There's still one missing piece of the puzzle. The alert dialog cannot be shown from a worker thread; it must be shown on the UI thread. I don't see how to use `Context` to run something on the UI thread. Did I miss some method in that class (or any other class?)

Comment: @HairOfTheDog yes you are right you need to run it in `runOnUiThread` my post was just an attempt to answer your question quickly